# How can I test individual layers in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, convolution

I have constructed a 7 layer convolutional network, based off of the DEEP MNIST Expert tutorial. I have added two more convolutional layers.

Everything runs well, but I would like to attempt to input 1024 x 10 arrays directly into the fully connected layer, and circumvent the convolutional layers.

Is there any way to do this without rebuilding the entire network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Between the convolutional layers and the fully connected layer, create a place holder for the input to the fully connected layer: `input_to_fc = tf.placeholder_with_default(previous_layer, shape=(None, 1024*10))`. You can bypass the convolutional layers by feeding the input directly to the `input_to_fc` tensor.

Example:

```
...
conv = tf.layers.conv2d(...)
flatten = tf.layers.flatten(...)
input_to_fc = tf.placeholder_with_default(flatten, shape=OUTPUT_SHAPE_OF_PREVIOUS_LAYER))
fc = tf.layers.dense(input_to_fc, ...)
```

Comment: A few questions: Is the shape simply one dimensional here? If so, why can it not be a two dimensional matrix? Second, why does FC exist? It seems like it is just code to flatten the input_to_fc tensor. Third, conv can just be any 1024 x 10 tensor I have, right?

Comment: It was just a example, edited to make it more general.  You can insert tf.placeholder_with_default () where ever you want to pass the inputs to the layers below directly. If you don't pass inputs then it defaults to the above layer.

Comment: Thank you so much!